Volumetric Emission Material Appears Black in Blender 4.2.3 LTS
I'm working in Blender 4.2.3 LTS and trying to use a volumetric emission material to create an animated fire effect. However, I’ve run into an issue: despite having ray tracing enabled, materials that should be illuminated by the emission appear completely black.

Ray tracing is active in my render settings. I followed some video tutorials suggesting the use of a lighting probe with baking, but it didn’t yield the desired results.
Here’s a snapshot of the volumetric emitter material I’m using (attached image or nodes setup if possible).

Has anyone else encountered this issue with volumetric emission, especially when animating effects like fire? Are there specific settings or techniques in Blender 4.2.3 LTS that could help improve the illumination on nearby surfaces?
is it a limitation of Blender 4.2 or a breaking change ? For example, "Volumetrics" seams to have been replaced by "Volume"
Edit 1
Using a Principled Volume node doesn't seem to make a difference.


You can't plug a surface shader into a volume shader socket. Try using Principled Volume instead of the Principled BSDF.

Principled Volume doesn't change anything, even with probe lightning but thanks, I will edit my question

I think this feature hasn't been implemented yet, indirect lighting from a volume emission. Raytracing in Eevee is still brand new.

so yes, it seams that for 4.3.2 you need to use cycle

Apart from EEVEE not being able to produce emissive volumetrics, here a tip if you want to it in Cycles: in the Principled Volume you don't need to set a general Color for the volume if you only want emission, this is actually scattering the light and therefore darkening your emission, especially if you increase the Density, the higher this value the darker the emission. So you should lower the Density to 0. And if you only want volumetric emission, no fog or smoke or anything, you can simply plug an Emission node into the Volume output. A Principle Volume is not necessary.

oh, interesting to know, I will try that tonight
